# onChildChanges works when a new child added

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listener

I am using child event Listener to get Data from the database. I had a problem with showing the data in a recycler view and after long hours of debugging I found that the cause of the problem is that onChildChanged is called when a new child is added.

this is the code that gives data from the database :

```
    public void startAsynkTask() {
    //TODO : search for a solution to this error
    AsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
            try {
                Socket sock = new Socket();
                sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 53), 1500);
                sock.close();
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            if ((boolean) o) {
                recreatingLists();
                ChildEventListener generalChallengesListener = new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                            Log.v("onChildAdded", "child added");
                            getChallengeData(dataSnapshot, "onChildAdded");
                            view.onDataFound();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        //TODO : note that the only changing handled is when challenge moves from uncompleted to completed state
                        if(!dataSnapshot.getKey().equals("questionsList")){
                            getChallengeData(dataSnapshot, "onChildChanged");
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < uncompletedChallengesList.size(); i++) {
                            if (uncompletedChallengesList.get(i).getId().equals(dataSnapshot.getKey())) {
                                uncompletedChallengesList.remove(i);
                                view.notifyAdapters(completedChallengesList.size(), uncompletedChallengesList.size(), "onChildChanged");
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        checkListsSizeAndAdjustViews();
                        view.hideProgressBar();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        startAsynkTask();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "فشل تحميل البيانات من فضلك تأكد من الاتصال بالانترنت", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        view.hideProgressBar();
                        Log.v("Logging", "error loading data : " + databaseError);
                    }
                };

                //this code gives data where current user is player 1
                player1Listener = challengesReference.orderByChild("player1Uid").equalTo(currentUserUid).addChildEventListener(generalChallengesListener);
                //this code gives data where current user is player 2
                player2Listener = challengesReference.orderByChild("player2Uid").equalTo(currentUserUid).addChildEventListener(generalChallengesListener);

                challengesReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        onInitialDataLoaded();
                        Log.v("ChallengesFragPresenter", "completed list size :" + completedChallengesList + " , uncompleted list size : " + uncompletedChallengesList);
                        challengesReference.removeEventListener(this);
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            } else {
                view.onNoInternetConnection();
            }
        }
    };

    asyncTask.execute();
}

public String getChallengeData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String tag) {
    Log.v("ChallengesFragPresenter", "get challenge data called");
    Log.v("ChallengesFragPresenter", "completedChallengesList : " + completedChallengesList.size()
            + ", uncompletedChallengesList " + uncompletedChallengesList.size());
    view.startCompletedChallengesAdapter(completedChallengesList);
    view.startUnCompletedChallengesAdapter(uncompletedChallengesList);

    GenericTypeIndicator<List<Question>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<Question>>() {
    };
    challenge = new Challenge();
    String challengeDate = dataSnapshot.child("date").getValue().toString();
    String challengeSubject = dataSnapshot.child("subject").getValue().toString();
    String challengeState = dataSnapshot.child("state").getValue().toString();
    String challengeId = dataSnapshot.getKey();
    ArrayList challengeQuestionsList = (ArrayList) dataSnapshot.child("questionsList").getValue(t);
    long player1Score = (long) dataSnapshot.child("player1score").getValue();
    long player2Score = (long) dataSnapshot.child("player2score").getValue();

    String player1Name = dataSnapshot.child("player1Name").getValue().toString();
    String player1Image = dataSnapshot.child("player1Image").getValue().toString();
    String player1Uid = dataSnapshot.child("player1Uid").getValue().toString();
    String player2Name = dataSnapshot.child("player2Name").getValue().toString();
    String player2Image = dataSnapshot.child("player2Image").getValue().toString();
    String player2Uid = dataSnapshot.child("player2Uid").getValue().toString();

    String challengerName, challengerImage;

    if (player1Uid.equals(currentUserUid)) {
        currentPlayer = 1;
        challengerName = player2Name;
        challengerImage = player2Image;
        challenge.setSecondChallengerUid(player2Uid);//second means that it is not the player who starts the challenge
        if (tag.equals("onChildAdded")) {
            player1childrenCount++;
        }
    } else {
        currentPlayer = 2;
        challengerName = player1Name;
        challengerImage = player1Image;
        challenge.setSecondChallengerUid(player1Uid);//second means that it is not the player who starts the challenge
        if (tag.equals("onChildAdded")) {
            player2childrenCount++;
        }
    }
    challenge.setCurrentPlayer(currentPlayer);
    challenge.setChallengerName(challengerName);
    challenge.setDate(challengeDate);
    challenge.setImage(challengerImage);
    challenge.setSubject(challengeSubject);
    challenge.setState(challengeState);
    challenge.setId(challengeId);
    challenge.setPlayer1Score(player1Score);
    challenge.setPlayer2Score(player2Score);
    challenge.setQuestionsList(challengeQuestionsList);
    String score;
    if (currentPlayer == 1) {
        score = player1Score + " : " + player2Score;
    } else {
        score = player2Score + " : " + player1Score;
    }
    challenge.setScore(score);
    if (challenge.getState().equals("اكتمل")) {
        Log.v("loggingC1", "value is " + !existsInCompletedChallengesList(challengeId));
        if (!existsInCompletedChallengesList(dataSnapshot.getKey())) {
            view.showCompletedChallengesTv();
            completedChallengesList.add(0, challenge);
            view.notifyAdapters(completedChallengesList.size(), uncompletedChallengesList.size(), "getChallengeData1");
        }
    }
    else if (challenge.getState().equals(refusedChallengeText)) {
        Log.v("loggingC2", "value is " + !existsInCompletedChallengesList(challengeId));
        if (!existsInCompletedChallengesList(dataSnapshot.getKey())) {
            view.showCompletedChallengesTv();
            completedChallengesList.add(0, challenge);
            view.notifyAdapters(completedChallengesList.size(), uncompletedChallengesList.size(), "getChallengeData3");
        }
    }
    else if (challenge.getState().equals(uncompletedChallengeText)) {
        Log.v("loggingC3", "value is " + !existsInUncompletedChallengesList(dataSnapshot.getKey()));
        if (!existsInUncompletedChallengesList(challengeId)) {
            view.showUncompletedChallengesTv();
            uncompletedChallengesList.add(0, challenge);
            view.notifyAdapters(completedChallengesList.size(), uncompletedChallengesList.size(), "getChallengeData2");
        }
    }

    return player1Uid;
}
```

I am using asynk task at the begging to checl the internet connection if there is internet connection it will start loading the data. The image shows the structre of my childrens in the database

[image]

Comment: where are you exactly having the problem ? poblating the RecyclerView with the data or fetching it ?

Comment: @Gastón Saillén The problem isn't in the recycler View the problem is that I remove the element in onChildChanged but when I debugged the code I found that when a child is added onChildChanged method works